# Can't get virtual devices to work on Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I've been trying to get Android Studio's virtual devices to work on my Mac, which is on High Sierra, Intel Haxm doesn't seem to be released for OSX 10.13, however I've installed it using guides I found on StackOverflow. But still I'm getting "/dev/kvm is not found".

Is there something I'm missing?
[Screenshot of the error message on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDWBH.png)

[Screen shot of the SDK tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M4Cq.png)

[Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XNmv.png)

Comment: Please paste screenshot of Android SDK Manager to see what SDK tools you have installed

Go to Tools > Android -> SDK Manager

Comment: I added the screen shot to my post

Comment: Select SDK Tools tab instead of SDK manager and upload the screenshot

Comment: added the new one

Answer (score 0):

Reboot to BIOS and enable VT or Virtualization Technology.

Comment: Is that a thing in Mac?